# Proving that $\sqrt{2} |z| \geq |x| + |y|$ for $z = x + iy$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

There is a question in my textbook:

> Verify that $\sqrt{2} |z| \geq |x| + |y|$ for $z = x + iy$ with $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> *Hint:* Boil this down to $(|x|-|y|)^2 \geq 0$.

I followed the hint and logically arrived at the fact that if $\sqrt{2} |z| \geq |x| + |y|$ then $(|x|-|y|)^2 \geq 0$ is true. However, I couldn't see how it helps me prove the converse to be true:

My work:

Let $z = x+iy$, then
\begin{align*}
        &\, \sqrt{2}|z| = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \geq |x| + |y| \\
    \iff&\, 2x^2 + 2y^2 \geq |x|^2 + |y|^2 +2|x||y| \\
    \iff&\, 2x^2 + 2y^2 - 2|x||y| \geq |x|^2 + |y|^2 \\
    \iff&\, (|x| - |y|)^2 \geq |x|^2 + |y|^2 \\
\implies&\, (|x| - |y|)^2 \geq 0.
\end{align*}

It seems like the last line needs an "iff" in order to be powerful in answering this problem, but I only see it going one way. Can someone please explain why it is an "iff" statement instead of just "if"?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you failed to recognize $\vert x\vert ^2=x^2$, and that you made a careless mistake in the last $\iff$ statement: the left hand side is not the same as what you claim it is.

Comment: Can anyone provide a geometric proof of this fact by interpreting $x$ and $y$ as the side-lengths of a right triangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{2}|z| = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \geq |x| + |y| \\
\iff 2x^2 + 2y^2 \geq |x|^2 + |y|^2 +2|x||y| \\
\iff 2x^2 + 2y^2 - 2|x||y| \geq |x|^2 + |y|^2 $$

At this point cancel $x^2+y^2$ from both sides to get

$$\iff x^2 + y^2 - 2|x||y| \geq 0 $$

$$\iff (|x| - |y|)^2 \geq 0 $$

And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \geq |x| + |y| \iff \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}2} \geq \frac{|x| + |y|}2$$

which is true by [**RMS-AM inequality**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality).